# Database is not created automatically while running spring boot integration tet

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, junit-jupiter

I am trying to run spring boot integration test using junit Jupiter and Java. I am pointing psql database, even I have given ddl auto create in properties file, but still database is not created.So my test cases are failing. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can define a test database in your "application-test.properties" file just like a normal Database. Postgres needs a database server running and can not run in Memory. Maybe you given "H2 Database" a try for your Testing Environment. If you want to stick with Postgres, then check out the framework "Testcontainers". With this framework you can create and run a docker container of your Postgres DB on test startup.